# How is the call getApplicationContext which returns a context type used in applications?

Tags: android

I'm new to java and android development. After spending few days working with java I started with android development. I've this question with regards to the Context class.

Context is a abstract class. Which cannot be instantiated and cannot be used to call methods unless it refers to a concrete subclass. Can someone tell how the call getApplicationContext which returns a context type is used in applications (a small snippet of how will be a huge help).

And also help me understand this statement Context context = getApplicationContext() getApplicationContext is an abstract method so when we use this call, which object implements this? Is it the ContextWrapper object of the current process (app) that gives this method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that `Context` is abstract does not mean that you cannot call methods on it - it mainly prevents you from instantiating it directly with a constructor. Which means that once you have a `Context` returned from `getApplicationContext`, you *can* call methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity you're implementing inherits from [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), which in turn inherits from Context. There are a few more classes on the way and one of them implements `getApplicationContext()` for you.

An abstract class cannot be instantiated, but can be inherited and any (or most...) class that fully implements all of its abstract methods can be instantiated. You can then reference instances of those classes as the abstract class for abstract handling. If you go with the good old employee example, when you calculate total salary, you don't care if the employee is a manager or a salesman.

```
// Employee is an abstract class with an abstract method - getSalary()
a = new ArrayList<Employee>();
a.add(new Manager())
a.add(new Salseman())
for (Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
  Employee e = i.next();
  System.out.println(e.getSalary());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked into the API provided and found that the ContextWrapper is implementing the methods and these methods are inherited by the application context and the activity context.